# Prevent multiple booking for same staff in microsoft booking for same time slot

Tags: calendar, microsoft365, microsoft-graph-booking

i want to Prevent multiple booking for same staff in microsoft booking .like right now multiple booking are getting created for same time slot

I tried following

- in the service section - assign buffer to 1 hour before and after
- in availability option -general availability -  set bookable when staff are free
- also its suggested to add 365 group and ad staff in it . but right now I don't have access to it .

[image]

Comment: I am looking for this same answer now and I have a MSFT contact to confirm this missing feature or missunderstanding. Currently I am going to develop a solution to prevent multiple bookings with a synchronized api. From what I see in the graph api now there is nothing to set nor is there anything that prevents double booking through GRAPH api. If I come up with the solution I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is available for resources like rooms but not for individuals. They expect you to look at your calendar before accepting, which I get, but I would also prefer if it automatically rejected meetings (or warned) that are booked over something else.

This will walk you through setting up zero tolerance for double booking resources, but unfortunately not for individuals.

https://help.askcody.com/scheduling-options-and-permissions-inside-office-365-and-exchange